# Distinguishing maven releases/snapshots from trunk than the ones from branches when getting latest dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, nexus, artifactory

I am working on project to automate maven releases for large set of inter-dependent modules. First the task involves getting the latest versions for internal dependencies. Than order the builds in a way every project is built before it’s needed.  Hopefully that combination will get me to my goal of one click bulk release.

However my biggest problem is:
We branch projects from time to time and we do releases/snapshots to Nexus repo manager from that branch. Obviously because the groupId and ArtifactId are the same as the trunk- Snapshots/Releases from trunk and one from branches end up in the same place in nexus.

In a scenario where we have projectA with a trunk version  1.1.x
And projectB → projectA version 1.1.x
So if I use the version-plugin to get the latest dependencies for B, I will get the latest. (perfect)

However if I later branch ProjectA with a version 1.2.0 and add changes that I don’t want projectB to pick  up or could potentially break it.
Now next time I run projectB and I use the version plugin to get the latest , The plugin will get the branch version (1.2.0) for ProjectA, as it’s numerically the latest. And there you go, projectB  build fails.

I have so far tried adding a classifier to the artifact to distinguish between the two but I later realised the plugin does not act upon the classifier.

This give me so much frustration and will appreciate any hints or advice

Answer (score 1):

Simple use proper/diffrent artifact names for branches. You can automatically create proper artifact names [Maven Release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/branch.html)

```
mvn --batch-mode release:branch -DbranchName=my-branch-1.2 -Dproject.rel.org.myCompany:projectA=1.2 -Dproject.dev.org.myCompany:projectA=2.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: Hi thanks for taking to the time to reply. I already thought about releasing branches under a different groupId, but because that will make it a different artifacts my team leader did not like that. Any other solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The typical approach to solve this problem is to use branch names as version classifiers and that approach works for all scenarios I have seen so far. What problem did you have with this?

Comment: Excellent suggestion, that was my first bullet. But my problem started when i've tried to get the latest version for my internal dependencies automatically. I was using the version plugin for that job.My tests showed that the plugin replaced the version number with the latest version number even though it does not correspondent to the specified classifier. Then, obviously maven failed to resolve from the local repo something with that GAV and classifier. The plugin ignores the classifier filter when evaluating(very disappointing).
i need to pick the latest versions for my internal dependencies

Comment: Yes.. automation with the versions plugin would require you to control it tighter and not rely on the calculatated defaults. But you can use e.g. an external script to do the version updates in which you set the newVersion parameter and therefore make sure the classifier is not lost. Or you could even patch the plugin to support classifier how you want it to work or create your own custom fork of it.. all these are better than trying other things imho.

Comment: Thanks Manfred, I always had in mind to write some kind of scripts or even own plugin to do the job. But I have limited time to finish this. And i was hoping there should be someone out there who has been on this road before and have a solution as i thought this to be a common hurdle. I am very surprised to this limitation. I even tried the classifier approach with the version range with the same result as version plugin. Maven just ignores the classifier.

Comment: Hm.. how are you doing your branch classified snapshot version. I know this works as I have used this multiple times in the past..

Comment: sorry, do you mean, how am i adding the classifier to the branches?
If that's what you meant, I have just passed a -Dclassifier=${branch.name} when deploying snapshots or releases for branches.

Comment: E.g. a working version string would be 1.2.3-brancha-SNAPSHOT and that would be picked up differently from 1.2.3-branchb-SNAPSHOT. If you use that across all our modules it would never mix them up.

Comment: ok How would i able to get the latest version for the brancha. And how maven release plugin will treat that extras string in the version string when releasing.

Comment: The latest version will be based on your version which includes the branch so there are different latest versions per branch. All components are effectively separated by branch. And with regards to the release plugin it depends on your usage and SCM system. You will must likely have to manually provide the right strings for each release. And releasing off a branch is possible depending SCM.. worst case do it manually without the release plugin.

Comment: thanks again Manfred. [here](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Distinguishing-artifacts-created-on-branches-td3344427.html) is another forum this issue has been discussed. As Lindsay Smith is mentioning right at the bottom of the post, the version plugin will not help when it comes to dynamically pull the latest version for that branch. I think as you mentioned earlier the only way forward is to add an extension to the version plugin to consider classifiers